# combine two angular service calls - angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two service calls. One which returns a list of products and the other one which returns a list of inventory for those products.

My requirement is to merge these two calls so that I can display them in a table. That is a product along with its current inventory.

I am really lost as to how I can combine these two separate service calls. Both have `sku` has common column name.

service call 1 product

```
  getProducts() {
    this.http
      .get<{ message: string; products: any }>(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/products'
      )
      .pipe(
        map(productData => {
          return productData.products.map(product => {
            return {
              sku: product.sku,
              style_code: product.style_code,
              id: product._id
            };
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe(transformedProducts => {
        this.products = transformedProducts;
        this.productsUpdated.next([...this.products]);
      });
  }
```

service call 2, both have `sku` in common

```
  getInventory() {
    this.http
      .get<{ message: string; inventory: any }>(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/inventory'
      )
      .subscribe(inventoryData => {
        this.inventory = inventoryData.inventory;
        this.inventoryUpdated.next([...this.inventory]);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the forkJoin of RXJS to call multiple service all together, see the bellow code:

```
 forkJoin(
     this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/products'),
     this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/inventory?prodId=${this.proId}`)
 ).subscribe( data => {             
        const [products, inventory] = data; 
},err => {          
    // show errors
});
```

You need to import `import { forkJoin  } from 'rxjs';`

Answer (score 1):

ForkJoin comes to rescue here.

```
const productService = this.http.get<{ message: string; products: any }>('http://localhost:3000/api/products').pipe(//your piping);
const inventorySerivce = this.http.get<{ message: string; inventory: any }>('http://localhost:3000/api/inventory').pipe(//your piping);
```

Then use forkJoin,

```
forkJoin([productService,inventoryService]).subscribe([productData,inventoryData] => {  
  this.products = productData;
  this.productsUpdated.next([...this.products]);
  this.inventory = inventoryData.inventory;
  this.inventoryUpdated.next([...this.inventory]);
});
```